# Categorical representations of absolute Galois groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

I am looking for interesting examples of categorical representations of absolute Galois groups of arithmetic fields. Pointers to the literature would be appreciated.